# Any efficient way to code a multichoice logit model?

Tags: r

I am trying to model a choice situation in which more than 1 alternatives may be chosen in each observation. This is different from a multinomial logit model and the multichoice model is specified in Ophem, Stam and Praag 1999. Here is an illustration:

Given alternatives A, B, C, and D,

Multinomial logit: we observe a person choose A. Multichoice logit: we observe a person chooses A and B.

I wrote my R code to calculate the choice probability of each observation:

```
multichoice = function(x) { 
  #x is exp(U), y is choice, both for each observation. 
  y = x[(length(x)/2+1):length(x)]
  x = x[1:(length(x)/2)]
  u0 = sum(x[y==0])
  u1 = x[y==1]
  for (i in 1:length(u1) ) {
    if (i == 1) {
      if (length(u1)==1) {
        prob0 = u1/c(u1+u0)
      } else {  
        matrixu0pluscombu1 = rbind( u0, combn(u1,i) ) 
        prob0 = 1 + (-1)^i*( sum(matrixu0pluscombu1[1,]/colSums(matrixu0pluscombu1) )  )      
      }
    } else {
      matrixu0pluscombu1 = rbind( u0, combn(u1,i) )
      prob0 = prob0 + (-1)^i*( sum(matrixu0pluscombu1[1,]/colSums(matrixu0pluscombu1) )  )      
      }  
  }
  return(prob0)
}
```

The dataset x should have two parts. The first-half columns should be the exponential of the deterministic part of the utility say, exp(V1, V2, V3, V4), and the second-half columns should be the discrete choice, say, c(1,0,0,1). Here is the code to run on a sample observation:

multichoice( c(c(1,2,3,4), c(0,1,0,1) ) ) # the answer should be 7/30

Then I need to use the apply function to do it for every observation to the probability and likelihood. My question is: my code involves some loops that may lower the speed when I optimize the likelihood function. Is there any way that I can make it faster or whether there is any other function I can use to estimate this multichoice logit model?

Thank you.